# How to update gradle file?

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

How to update **gradle** file in **android studio**

**Note: I use Flutter not java**

Error Message log

> Error running Gradle: ProcessException: Process
>   "E:\Courses\Programming\Mobile Apps\the complete flutter
>   course\flash-chat-flutter\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'E:\Courses\Programming\Mobile Apps\the complete flutter course\flash-chat-flutter\android\app\build.gradle' line: 25
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>
>   > ASCII
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 5s   Command: E:\Courses\Programming\Mobile Apps\the
>   complete flutter course\flash-chat-flutter\android\gradlew.bat
>   app:properties
>
> Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the
>   android/ folder.

Comment: can you please add your both build.gradle files in the question to figure out the issue?

Comment: this is a google drive link to my both build.gradle files.. plz, review it

[link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17jw0KE7Aq4wgMj7kaVzbEbYz5aj377ly)